# Markdown usage in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

Hi I get this error when passing a string to the markdown package. I am not familiar with Markdown. If you could please tell me why it doesn't accept this string , it will be of help.

My error is :

> The following assertion was thrown during paint(): Assertion failed:
> file:///Users/anishhemachandran/Developer/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/rendering/box.dart:1930:12
> hasSize "RenderBox was not laid out: RenderRepaintBoundary#0e39e
> relayoutBoundary=up4 NEEDS-PAINT"

```
class MarkdownTest extends StatelessWidget {
  final String markdownString = 'Hello!';

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Card(
      color: AppColors.background,
      child: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
        child: Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
          children: [
            Row(
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
              children: [
                Container(
                  margin: EdgeInsets.all(10),
                  child: Markdown(
                    data: markdownString,
                  ),
                ),
                SizedBox(width: 10),
              ],
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: If you do not want the padding or scrolling behavior, use the MarkdownBody instead.

Comment: Thanks @jabbson .